# Can I replace multiple similar methods with a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, templates

I have several functions that takes in list of objects and create a chart Series out of them.  It looks repetetive and I feel like I can replace these similar looking functions with Lambda expressions or templates, but haven't been able to figure out how to deal with the different property names on each object.  Can someone help?

Here's what I have:

```
private static Series getBuysSeries(List<Order> buys)
{
    var series = new Series();
    foreach (var buy in buys)
    {
        series.Points.AddXY(buy.Price, buy.Quantity);
    }
    return series;
}

private Series getPriceSeries(List<Trade> trades)
{
    var series = new Series();
    foreach (var trade in trades)
    {
        series.Points.AddXY(trade.DateTimeUTC, trade.UnitPrice);

    }
    return series;
}
```

I would think it could look like:

```
private static Series getBuysSeries(List<Order> buys)
{

    return getSeries<Order>(buys);
}

private Series getPriceSeries(List<Trade> trades)
{
    return getSeries<Trade>(trades);
}

private Series getSeries<T>(List<T> list)
{
    ...do the loop but account for property names...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. At least, you may be able to. For example - having changed the method names to be more conventional, and using generic type inference for the method calls:

```
private static Series GetBuysSeries(List<Order> buys)
{
    return GetSeries(buys, buy => buy.Price, buy => buy.Quantity);
}

private Series GetPriceSeries(List<Trade> trades)
{
    return getSeries<Trade>(trades,
                            trade => trade.DateTimeUtc,
                            trade => trade.UnitPrice);
}

private Series GetSeries<T>(List<T> list,
                            Func<T, double> selector1,
                            Func<T, double> selector2)
{
    var series = new Series();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        series.Points.AddXY(selector1(item), selector2(item));
    }
    return series;
}
```

Now that's assuming that `AddXY` takes two `double` values. That seems a little odd for `trade.DateTimeUTC`, but it's hard to give more specific advice without knowing how `Series.AddXY` is defined.

If you actually want to call a different *overload* of `AddXY` in each case, it'll be a bit trickier. In that case you may need to use dynamic typing, e.g.

```
private Series GetSeries<T>(List<T> list,
                            Func<T, dynamic> selector1,
                            Func<T, dynamic> selector2)
{
    var series = new Series();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // Here the overload is determined at execution time...
        series.Points.AddXY(selector1(item), selector2(item));
    }
    return series;
}
```

Comment: that's a really thoughtful answer.  I'll have a look at this and get back to you.

Comment: +1 for the dynamic typing part of this answer. Did not know that was possible :-)

Comment: dude, that was amazing.  Exactly what I was looking for!  It turns out DateTimeUTC is a DateTime object so I just changed the template signature.   private Series GetSeries<T, U, V>(List<T> list, Func<T, U> selector1, Func<T, V> selector2)

Comment: @FistOfFury: So is `AddXY` also generic? Or does it take `object` parameters?

Comment: @JonSkeet AddXY has a (double,double) signature and a (object, params object[]) signature http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487988(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @FistOfFury: And are you happy with it always calling the latter? That's the difference between using `dynamic` and not - if you're not using dynamic typing, the overload is chosen at compile-time, and it *can't* choose the `(double, double)` one because it doesn't know that your conversions will be to `double`.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're saying my code will always call the object signature?  why wouldn't it call the (double, double) parameter when both types are double?